# How can I use MySQL JSON functions with Mybatis?

Tags: mysql, json, mybatis

I'm trying to use MySQL JSON functions with Mybatis.

```java
@Results(id = "findTestByCountry", value = {
        @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true)
    })
@Select("SELECT id" +
        "FROM tests" +
        "WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(countries, #{country})")
List<Test> findTestByCountry(String country);
```

But it fails like below.

```
Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.
```

Is it impossible to use JSON functions with Mybatis?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with MyBatis. It says that the value of `countries` is not a valid JSON. The following query returns rows with invalid JSON : `select id from tests where json_valid(countries) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Type Handler class that extends **BaseTypeHandler** from **String**. Reference: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers

```
public class JsonStringToStringTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {...}
```

The select statement:

```
@Select("SELECT id" +
        "FROM tests" +
        "WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(countries, #{country, typeHandler=com.example.JsonStringToStringTypeHandler})")
```

JsonStringToStringTypeHandler Class

```
public class JsonStringToStringTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int columnIndex, String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(columnIndex, gson.toJson(parameter));
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return deserialize(resultSet.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return deserialize(resultSet.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return deserialize(callableStatement.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    private String deserialize(final String json) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, String.class);
    }
}
```